# Error when creating table with more than 9 columns using {*} shortcut

Tags: tables, errors, columns

I can't imagine that this hasn't been asked before, but googling doesn't help me find the answer.

Creating a table with 9 columns using the shortcut `{*9{l}}` works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*9{l}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But when I get into double digits, I get an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*10{l}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> ! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array
>   arg.

How can I use the shortcut `{*}` with >9 columns?

Comment: Maybe `\begin{tabular}{*{10}{l}}`? Seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to wrap the relevant number into curly braces if it is not single digit.

So

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{12}{l}}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

should cut it.

Comment: I usually wait 24+ hrs before accepting an answer, but I can't imagine anyone else wanting to provide an alternative answer (that's better) than this.

Comment: @Sverre An alternative answer (only to support you imagination}: \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\catcode`?=\active
\def?{12}

%\begin{tabular}{*{12}{l}}
\begin{tabular}{*?{l}}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document} :-)